# Can I use vinegar or bleach to clean manganese from my plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

Is it ok to pour vinegar or bleach in my well in order to clear manganese from the pipes?  If the answer is yes, how much should I pour in the well?

Thank you very much...

Comment: Bleach is basic and vinegar is acidic so these are not equivalent options.  I've never heard of using bleach for hard water buildup.  Vinegar does work but how much vinegar are you able to get your hands on?

Comment: "in your well" ?  Do you mean a well that provides water for your house?  Ie: pull water from the ground?

Comment: Why do you think you have a manganese material in your pipes ?

Comment: I wondered that, too. A cursory search doesn't return much on hard deposits, just dissolved mineral.

Comment: I found [this page](http://www.reddiplumbingwichita.com/blog/general/problems-and-solutions-for-hard-water-buildup): "**Clogged water pipes** Lime scale, made up of magnesium and calcium deposits, can build up in your plumbing system and reduce the flow of water through the pipes. PVC and copper pipes are not as susceptible to this problem, but it is a big issue for steel pipes."  Do you have steel pipes?  Usually, a little scale on the inside of pipes is a good thing.  The Flint disaster was a direct result of the loss of this protective coating.

Comment: Using vinegar might mobilize lead if you have copper pipes sweated with lead solder. When was the house built? What are the water pipes made from?